# Where did the humans used as food in Makai come from?

Tags: yu-yu-hakusho

At in the last episodes of *Yu Yu Hakusho*, when Yusuke met the Raizen's subordinates, they explained that Raizen stopped using humans as food, but his subordinates didn't. Moreover, the other two Makai Kings (Yomi and Mukuro) still use humans as the main food source. So it's possible to say that all their subordinates and maybe others youkai do that.

However since it's difficult to open a gate between ningenkai (human world) and makai (demon world), given the difficulty Sensui had. Was there an explanation to how could all the Class A/S youkai get so many humans?

Comment: Yes! Is there anyone who can answer this? because this was never explained as far as I know and it's a major plothole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that it was very difficult for A- and S-class demons to reach the human world. So the lords definitely weren't harvesting humans for themselves.

But it seems that it isn't that hard for demons of lower classes to reach the human world. Hiei and his gang managed to get through early in the series. The demon Rando gets through and enters Genkai's disciple selection tournament. The Four Saint Beasts send lower-level demons to scout in the human world, and probably could have come themselves if they weren't sealed inside their castle, since [according to the wiki](http://yuyuhakusho.wikia.com/wiki/The_Four_Saint_Beasts) they were all C-class or lower. Hiei's sister Yukina manages to get into the human world, where she is captured by Gonzo Tarukane and then rescued by Yusuke and Kuwabara. Several demon teams compete in the Dark Tournament, which is in the human world, IIRC.

So I think we can assume that lower-ranked demons were coming into the human world and harvesting humans to bring back to the Demon World for the A- and S-class demons to feast on. This is similar to what the Saint Beasts were doing with their scouts.